# Optimize toy airplane from a cocktail-straw and two paper rings

Tags: aerodynamics

Thrown horizontally with small ring pointing forward (both rings oriented upwards at start). Both rings having same width (2.5 cm) and length 12.5 cm (small ring) and 2*12.5 cm (big ring). Paper fixed with small stripes of Scotch tape.

This toy flies OK, but tends to dive too much down (at the small ring tip).

Please help me understand aerodynamics of its flight and let me know any tips how to make this design better. Besides, how shall I best throw it (any upward angle to horizontal plane, hold it in the middle of the straw or with some offset, etc), how to balance it (I can wrap Scotch tape to make certain parts heavier, etc).

[image]
[image]

Comment: *This toy flies OK, but tends to dive too much down (at the small ring tip)* Obviously you need to move the CoG a little toward the big ring. Use a little blutak blob.

Comment: Your question about aerodynamics is too broad. Your questions about optimising design and launch are best answered by experimenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some basic information about normal airplanes.

There needs to be an upward-turning tendency, known as *decalage*.
You can accomplish this by putting a little upward bend in your straw.

Then, it needs to be *slightly* nose-heavy.
If it isn't, it will follow a scalloped up-down path, or even fly backwards.

If you get those right, it will find its natural speed and glide beautifully.